# Can apps with Baidu Web Push work on non-Chinese devices out-of-the-box?

Tags: applications, push-notifications

For our client, we are developing an application where the majority of the users are located in Mainland China and we need to support push notifications for this group. Since Google and GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) is blocked in China, we are looking to implement [Baidu Web Push](http://push.baidu.com/).

In the Amazon documentation, [handling Push Notifications from Baidu Cloud Push](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-sdk-android-push-baidu.html), they state the following:

> Install your app on to a Baidu-enabled device and capture the generated device token.

Is Baidu Web Push only supported on certain Chinese devices? GCM requires the Google Play Services to be installed and we are wondering if Baidu needs something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've integrated the Baidu Cloud Push on our own device (non-Chinese), in Europe, and we were able to receive a push from the Baidu Cloud Push Console.

So apps with Baidu Web Push do not need any other services installed and will work out of the box.